# How to get objects count in php

Tags: oop

How to get object count in PHP, if possible with examples? 
In this example, I should get "4" as a result :

```
              <?php
              class myclass
               {
              public $i=0;
              public static $j=0;

                  }
                $obj=new myclass();
                $obj1=new myclass();
                $obj2=new myclass();
                $obj3=new myclass();
                echo $obj-;
               ?>
```

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Comment: welcome to SO. please have a read of [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  As it stands, I for one have no idea what youre talking about.

Comment: Please  explain with exaples

Comment: <?php
class myclass
{
public $i=0;
public static $j=0;
public function __construct()
{
    $i++;
 $j++;
}   
           
}
$obj=new myclass();
echo $obj->$i;
echo $obj->$j;
$obj1=new myclass();
echo $obj1->$i;
echo $obj1->$j;
$obj2=new myclass();
echo $obj2->$i;
echo $obj2->$j;
$obj3=new myclass();
echo $obj3->$i;
echo $obj3->$j;
?>                                Please  check this code. i want answer with 4

Answer (score 1):

You can either :

1. Increment a var each time you instanciate a new object

   new object created
   Add 1 to the var

   second object created
   Add 1 to the var
2. Put those objects into an array, and get the array size

   create an array
   add a new object into that array
   add another object to that array
   get the array's size/length
3. Put a static member "count" that's increased in the constructor

   In the class constructor, add 1 to the static var; much like the first version

---

If those ideas ain't familiar to you, I strongly suggest you to dive in a tutorial and learn step by step

Comment: Please explain with examples

Comment: As I told you, you should dive into a tutorial buddy... Those are basic codes you should be able to get easily, try to find a "from zero" tutorial on your search engine. Just giving code won't help you, you won't understand it clearly and will just copy/paste it. - this website may be of good help (for example) : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762